# Calculate unique values in one column based upon non-null values in another

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

Working through this: https://towardsdatascience.com/exploratory-statistical-data-analysis-with-a-real-dataset-using-pandas-208007798b92

A little shy of half way through, the author calculates the number of unique medal winners with this line of code:

```
medal_winners = len(df[df.Medal.fillna('None') != 'None'].Name.unique())
```

This seems rather unnecessarily complicated, so I am trying to simplify it.

Ultimately, I believe that line of code is saying:  first check for non-null values in the 'Medal' column, then get the number of unique names who have won medals.

To me this is:  check 'Medal' for a non-null value, then groupby name and get the number of unique
names who have won a medal.  The type of medal does not matter, so if John Doe won three different medals, I only count him once.  All I want is the total number of unique medal winners.

I came up with this:

```
medal_winners = df['Medal'].notnull().groupby['Name'].nunique()
```

But I get this error:  `TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable`

I have tried other variations on what I think should work, but every time I get an error.

I thought the above would work, but it doesn't.

Comment: Switch to parentheses on your `groupby` call.

Comment: What @FelipeLanza means is `.groupby()` instead of `.groupby[]`.  Use `df['Medal'].notnull().groupby('Name').nunique()`.

Comment: KeyError: 'Name'  is what I get when I make that change.

Comment: @MarkS Have you looked at the output of each step of the expression in turn?

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out, but even with groupby() the solution is still longer than I expected -- or maybe I should say I did not achieve what I thought would be increased simplification:

```
medal_winners = df[df['Medal'].notnull()].groupby('Name')['Name'].nunique().sum()
```

Both my groupby() based solution and the authors yield an answer of:  28202

Comment: Turns out I don't need groupby() at all: ```medal_winners = df[df['Medal'].notnull()]['Name'].nunique()```